# .Net Core publish/deploy to Windows-Server-2019 from macos

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, windows-server-2019

I developed a WebApp using *ASP.NET Core*. I used *VSCode* on mac and also *Visual Studio Professional 2017 for Mac* (depending on my mood).  Publishing on *Azure* through *Git* was pretty easy as there were a lot of resources to follow (especially Microsoft official documentation).  I found out that Azure subscriptions are pretty expensive and i looked for a cheaper option.  1&1 Ionos seemed to be a nice alternative. I subscribed to the WINDOWS .NET CORE hosting service, it come up with storage, database and domain. ([cf](https://www.ionos.com/hosting/windows-hosting))  and it’s running the last version of windows server. Well.
 But i couldn’t find nothing as documentation for publishing my website.  I saw on Visual Studio than i can publish my project to a local folder on my pc and then copy paste the generated files on the server through FTP but i don’t even know where should i paste those files. Am i thinking/doing wrong ?

Comment: That depends on the hosting provider. Look at their documentation or ask them

Comment: Have you contact their support team? I believe they have documentation. Please also read http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/How-to-Publish-ASPNET-Core-2.aspx. Maybe it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it was as simple as this (in order to make it work)
First run from terminal "dotnet publish -c release" on the folder where .csproj is located. 
This will generate files at bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/
Copy paste those files (under publish) through FTP at the root of your hosting service.